# How do i implement a check on the password to see if there is a number?

Tags: java

How do i implement a check on the password to see if there is a number? I have a check in place 
for the length but the password also requires a number, how do I accomplish this? I know that it has something to do with the char class and a loop but everything I have tried has led me into a wall. Any advice would help.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Pasword
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String password1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please Enter A Password That Contains 6 - 10 Characters One Of Which Is A Number");
        int len = password1.length();

        while((len < 6) || (len > 10))
        {
            password1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "! INVALID !Please Enter A Password That Contains 6 - 10 Characters One Of Which Is A Number");
            len = password1.length();
        }

        String password2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "!PASSWORD VALIDATOR! Please Re-Enter Password");
        int len2 = password2.length();

        while((len2 < 6) || (len2 > 10))
        {
            password2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "! INVALID !Please Re-Enter");
            len2 = password2.length();
        }
                if(password1.equals(password2))
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Accepted");
                }
                else
                {
                    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Passwords do not match, Pleas Re-enter");
                }

    }

}
```

I am new to java and have learned a lot about it, Im just having an issue implementing the knowledge.
Thank You

Comment: Read the javadoc of String and look for a method allowing to get the chars in the string. Then read the javadoc of Character and look for a method allowing to know if a char is a digit. Then use a loop.

Answer (score 2):

I would use some regular expression.

```
System.out.println("x123".matches("(.*?)\\d(.*?)"));
System.out.println("xyz".matches("(.*?)\\d(.*?)"));
```

Comment: You probably meant `(.*)` not `(.*?)`, but you don't need the `.*` in the regex anyway.  `"ab12ab".matches("\\d")` will return true as it looks for one digit anywhere in the string.

Comment: No I'm not.  I use regexes every day.  `^.*\\d.*$` matches the whole string (notice the ^ and $ characters).  Also, `.*` means zero or more of any character, so the `?` is not needed (ZERO or more, not ONE or more).

Comment: @daiscog I don't use them every day but you're wrong. I think you're maybe thinking some other language here, not Java. Not sure.

Comment: Apologies, `String#matches` does match against the whole string by default (which isn't usual for regexes).  But my point about using `.*` instead of `(.*?)` is still valid.

Comment: @daiscog I just use a reluctant quantifier ? as I find this more explicit here. What you suggest about .* will work too, yes.

Comment: Fair enough, I just thought that simply using `.*` looks simpler and also I assumed that using `(.*?)` would involve more work for the regex engine (although admittedly any extra work would obviously be neglegable).

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through each character to check if it is a digit:

```
boolean hasNumber = false;
for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    if (Character.isDigit(password1.charAt(i)) {
        hasNumber = true;
        break; // no need to keep searching
    }
}
if (!hasNumber) {
    // password1 does not contain a number
}
```

Or you could use [String#matches](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29):

```
if (!password1.matches(".*\\d.*")) {
    // password1 does not contain a number
}
```

Comment: The second example is incorrect. `!password1.matches("\\d")` will only match the following strings "0", "1", "2", "3", .., "9". Because it means that the string has a length of 1 character and that character is a digit.

Answer (score -1):

convert  string password into int , if there is a erreur then it's not a number

to convert string into integer use  passwd-number=*Integer.parseInt*(passwd-string)